# momentjs undefined in some places

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, undefined, momentjs

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Pointy I had a look at my scripts I found out that I had Momentjs after my own script. Fixed.

I have a strange problem with Momentjs. Moment() is undefined in some places of my code

```
function init_Calendar() {
var now = moment(); // undefined

/** some unrelated code here **/ 
}

function monthLoadSuccess(data, status, jqXHR) {
var sortedAppointments = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var date = moment(data[i].Date); // successfully turns ASP.NET JSON Date into   Moment object
    /** more code **/
}
```

Both methods are in the same file. When I run Firebug on the page I am able to call moment() from the console, but for some reason it is undefined on the page.

I have included

```
<script>
    moment().format();
</script>
```

At the bottom of my html after momentjs, does not help.

Comment: Post the HTML that imports your scripts; that's got to be where the problem is.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks I had a look at my scripts and found out that i have put momentjs after my scripts. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev If you solved the issue, don't mark it in the title, just add it as an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Pointy I had a look at my scripts I found out that I had Momentjs after my own script.